# re-writing a mathematical expression with trig idnetities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$$ u = \frac{g}{c} A \left\{e^{-y/R_{o}} \sin \left(kx - \omega{t} \right) - e^{y/R_{o}} \sin \left(kx + \omega{t} \right)\right\} $$

which needs to be simplified using the following assumptions

$$y = \frac{b}{2}, x = x_{1}, q = \frac{b}{2R_{o}}$$

Using some notes found online, here is my attempt:

$$ u = \frac{gA}{c} \left\{e^{-b/2R_{o}} \sin \left(kx - \omega{t} \right) - e^{b/2R_{o}} \sin \left(kx + \omega{t} \right)\right\} $$

$$ u = \frac{gA}{c} \left\{ e^{-b/2R_{o}} \left( \sin\left(kx - \omega{t}\right) - \sin \left(kx + \omega{t}\right)\right) - \left(e^{b/2R_{o}} - e^{-b/2R_{o}}\right) \sin \left(kx - \omega{t}\right)\right\} $$

$$ u = \frac{gA}{c} \left\{e^{-q} \left( 2 \cos kx \sin \omega t \right) - 2 \sinh{q} \sin\left( kx + \omega{t}\right) \right\} $$

$$ u = \frac{2gA}{c} \left\{ e^{-q} \cos kx \sin \omega{t} - \sinh{q} \left( \sin kx \cos \omega{t} + \cos kx \sin \omega{t} \right) \right\} $$

$$ u = \frac{2gA}{c} \left\{ \sin \omega{t} \left( \cos kx_{1} \left( e^{-q} - \sinh{q} \right)\right) - \cos \omega{t} \left( \sin{kx_{1}} \sinh{q} \right) \right\} $$

However, I am pretty sure that I've done something wrong with the trig identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us just focus on $$Z=e^{-\frac{y}{R}} \sin (k x- \omega t )-e^{\frac{y}{R}} \sin (k x+ \omega t)$$ Replace $$e^{\pm\frac{y}{R}} =\cosh(\frac{y}{R})\pm\sinh(\frac{y}{R})$$ $$\sin (k x\pm \omega t)=\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)\pm \cos(kx)\sin(\omega t)$$ and develop; this should simplify to $$Z=-2 \left(\sin (k x) \sinh \left(\frac{y}{R}\right) \cos ( \omega t)+\cos (k x) \cosh
   \left(\frac{y}{R}\right) \sin ( \omega t )\right)$$

Comment: Note that A is not equal to e^... but is part of the equation.

Comment: Sorry for the notation ! I edit now.